# Почему цикл while выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')

Tags: javascript, циклы, while

У меня есть такая функция, которая принимает массив и для каждого i-го запускает while который сравнивает arr[i][1] и arr[i+x+1] до тех пор, пока x меньше arr.length - 1. Мне кажется ошибки нет, но при выполнении функция выдает ошибку Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1'). Я сломал голову, но не понимаю в чем дело. Если кто-то сможет подсказать, я буду максимально признателен.

```
  function func (arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      let x = 0
      while (x < arr.length - 1) {
        if (arr[i][1] < arr[x + 1 + i][1]) {
          break
        } else {
          x++
          if (x == arr.length) {
            break
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  func([
    [1, 60],
    [2, 40],
    [3, 42],
    [15, 25]
  ])
```

Comment: Не надо ломать голову, используй отладку

Comment: Пока писал, понял в чем была ошибка. В условии while нужно было x сравнивать с arr.length - i - 1

Answer (score 0):

Пока писал вопрос, понял в чем была ошибка. В условии while нужно было x сравнивать с arr.length - i - 1